# How can I count number of Window with specific title on Linux by Python?

Tags: python, linux, x11

Here is my solution, but I think it's not a good one. Can anybody suggest me new solution, I want to enumarize windows, and get the Title property to compare by just using core library of python , not wnck or pygtk ...

```
def linux_CountWindowsByTitle(title):
    import commands
    XWinInfoOutput = commands.getoutput("xwininfo -all -root")
    resArray = XWinInfoOutput.split("\n")
    resRange = len(resArray) - 1
    res = 0
    #Parse each line of output
    for i in range(0, resRange):
        index = resArray[i].find("\"")   #Get index of Double quote
        if (index < 0):
            continue    #This line does not have title we need

        tmp = resArray[i].split("\": (")[0] #Remove tail
        windowName = tmp.split("\"",1)[1]   #Remove head
        if (UTILITY.Compare(title, windowName)):
            #LIBRARY.Report(windowName)
            res += 1

    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module `wnck`.

```
import wnck

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
window_list = wnck.Screen.get_windows(screen)

window_names = [ w.get_name() for w in window_list ]
```

In order to count the similar windows, you can create a dictionary:

```
count = window_names.count
wcounts = { item: item.count(item) for item in set(window_names) }
```

Where the dictionary will have as key the window title and the value will be the number of times the same name is repeated.

Slightly different, but you might find interesting to use is:

```
wdict = { w.get_name(): w for w in window_list }
wdict.has_key(title)
```

If you need the window later to other processing, you still have a reference handy in the `wdict`.  For instance, you can check properties, maximize it, minimize, and all typical operations that a window manager would do.

**Note**: For newer versions of `wnck` (>=3.0) you have to use PyGObject (GObject Introspection), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I did not try your solution yet but it's seem to be the good one that I need.

Comment: In that case, you would need a wrapper for `Xlib`, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python%20Xlib, but it is low level IMHO.

Comment: uhmm I write code for company so I can not use library arbitraryly. I must try to solve problem with core library :)

Comment: For future reference, you should mention it in your question.

Comment: sorry for that, I'm a non-experienced user on stackoverflow, I'll keep your words in mind